# DocuSign REST API: Correcting a document using api

Tags: api

How to Correct a document using api in docusign?
I have tried using update api from docusign but not able to achieve.

Comment: please add more things in question like what is the excat errors you are getting .Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: question need better explanation with more description of errors